# Xcode 5.1 Cordova iOS config.xml

Tags: xcode, cordova

I know there are several issues with the new version of xcode 5.1/cordova and it simply wont run apps on 64x bit devices / emu but I followed [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTjE.png) and now it somehow works (even though it spits 14 warnings in my case)

But for some reasons config.xml is still being ignored. It's in red and you can't edit it.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: i've had this problem with the red files in xcode browser and i managed to fix it just by opening the file in Finder. I know it's weird but that's what did it for me.

Comment: Are you using any Cordova plugins by any chance? I tried to use Camera / device plugins but the app wont simply start if you have those installed.

Comment: yes, using various plugins.

Comment: Could you update your question by correcting the link to the tutorial? I really struggle to make Xcode work with Cordova... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to close your xcode. Build again using cordova build and open up again your xcode then you can run your app.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately it does not work at all. I am getting like 10 errors: http://imgur.com/KUUvH2w

Comment: can u send me the project through dropbox so I can take a look at it